# How to reload python module from itself?

Tags: python

I have a python module with a lot of variables. These variables are used and changed by many other modules. And I want to reload this module from itself when it happens (for refresh).

How to do that?

**upd:** so.. this is me, question author, 8 years after the question publication date. I have zero idea why I would try to do something like that then.

If you read this, please attempt to use proper configuration management techniques (most of the time supplied by your framework) instead.

```
# ==================================
# foo.py

spam = 100

def set_spam(value):
    spam = value
    foo = reload(foo) # reload module from itself

# ==================================
# bar.py

import foo
print foo.spam # I expect 100
# assume that value changes here from some another modules (for example, from eggs.py, apple.py and fruit.py)
foo.set_spam(200)
print foo.spam # I expect 200
```

Comment: This sounds like a fairly bad idea...

Comment: @Wooble, okay, so.. what would you recommend? wrap all those variables as Singleton Class?

Comment: In your particular case, I think you just want `global spam` at the top of your `set_spam` function, but it's not entirely clear to me why you think reloading could possibly keep the value at 200. If anything, it will reset it to 100 immediately after setting it, which makes no sense.

Comment: @Wooble better than relying on the user to `reload(module)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation doesn't make sens at all. From [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload):

> reload(module): Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before.

So, `reload` make sens only from context of other module which performed `import` previously.

Comment: Well, it's in `sys.modules` globally, so it's not as nonsensical as it might sound. still...

Comment: Obviously the module should not be reloaded from the global scope but from a function which should be called from another module!

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with what you're trying to achieve, unless you're deliberately setting up a self-modifying code system, which it doesn't look like you are.

#### 1. Global variables

```
spam = 100

def set_spam(value):
    spam = value
    foo = reload(foo) #reload module from itself
```

This is not going to work.  Because of how Python closures work, your `spam = value` line is going to create a new *local* variable `spam` within your `set_spam` function, which then won't get used.  To properly change the value of the global `spam`, you have to use the `global` keyword, as such:

```
spam = 100

def set_spam(value):
    global spam
    spam = value
```

#### 2. Reloading modules "from themselves"

As far as I know, there's no way to actually do this, nor should you need to.   Any module you've `import`-ed is called from some other module, all the way up to `__main__`.  You would simply refresh it from that calling module.  Yes, you *could* attempt to self-import a module (though there might be infinite loop issues, as mentioned by mgilson), but even then (using an example named "foo"), if you had it import itself, you'd just have `foo.foo`, and doing something like `foo.reload(foo)` (if that's even valid) would simply reload the sub-`foo`, not the base one.

#### 3. Reloading `foo.py` at all

```
# ==================================
# foo.py

spam = 100

def set_spam(value):
    global spam
    spam = value
```

Note how at the top of this code, you're assigning 100 to `spam`.  *Every time you import the module*, you'll be doing that again.  So, even if you've already changed the value of `spam` in the code that's imported `foo`, when you reload the module, you'll actually be destroying the change you just made.  Example:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.spam
100
>>> foo.spam = 9
>>> foo.spam
9
>>> reload(foo)
>>> foo.spam
100
```

So if you want to keep the changes you've made to the variable in `foo`, you should **not** reload the module.  Furthermore, you really don't even need to use a `set_spam` function to change `spam`, you can just set it directly, as I did.

#### 4. Trying to use this "changed" module value in other modules

Finally, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, that's not going to work.  This is in large part because of something I mentioned in part 3, wherein every time you load `foo`, the `spam=100` line is going to reset the value of `spam`.  In the same way, if you import the `foo` module in two different other modules, when each one imports it, they're each going to start out with `spam = 100`, completely independently of what the other module does with `foo.spam`.  Example, if both `bar1.py` and `bar2.py` contain the line `import foo`:

```
>>> import bar1, bar2
>>> bar1.foo.spam
100
>>> bar2.foo.spam
100
>>> bar1.foo.spam = 200
>>> bar1.foo.spam
200
>>> bar2.foo.spam
100
```

With more explanation about what you're trying to do, we could help you restructure your code to make it work better.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.6.2 it is simple. Assume your module is named "t" and is defined as follows:

```
import imp

def reload():
    name="t"
    imp.load_module(name,*imp.find_module(name))

print("loaded")
```

After you have loaded this module add another member it and execute t.reload().

p.s. I guess everybody thinks this is a bad idea: they're probably right, but if you're interactively developing a module maybe it makes things more convenient. Just take it out before you distribute your code to others or they might get confused.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
import sys

reload(sys.modules[__name__])
```

NB, this does not work with the `main` module but with any other module.

Comment: No go:-> ImportError: Cannot re-init internal module __main__

Comment: Good catch, it works with module other than `main` though.

Comment: This works, however if you're inside function older version of function gets executed - but then you can define wrapper - one main function with reload function call, and one wrapped function which gets updated and it will be called after reload()

Answer (score 2):

You also can count the times the module was reloaded!:

### mymodule.py

```
import importlib
import sys

count = 0
var = 0

def refresh():
    global count
    c = count
    importlib.reload(sys.modules[__name__])
    count = c + 1
    print (f'reloaded {count} time(s)')
```

### main.py

```
import mymodule

mymodule.var = 'changed'
mymodule.refresh()
  # -> reloaded 1 times(s)
print(mymodule.var)
  # -> 0
mymodule.refresh()
  # -> reloaded 2 times(s)
```

Comment: the counter is reset to 0 every time the module is reloaded for the 4th line `count = 0`!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could do this cleanly without getting caught in an infinite loop.  Maybe it would be better to have a `reset` function?

```
def reset():
    global spam
    spam = 100
```

Note that this design still seems a little funky to me.  It seems like better data encapsulation would probably help you a lot in the long run -- Perhaps something like:

```
def new_namespace():
    return {'spam':100}
```

Then each of your other functions could accept a namespace dictionary as an argument rather than relying on the `foo` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the previous answer with the counter only initialized if it does not exist. Tested on python 3.8.6

```
# mod.py
import importlib, sys

a=0

def reload():
  
    importlib.reload(sys.modules[__name__])
    global i
    try:
        i += 1
    except:
        i = 1
    print(f'reloaded {i} time(s)')
```

---

```
# main.py
import mod

mod.a = 10
print (mod.a) # -> 10
mod.reload() # -> reloaded 1 time
print (mod.a) # -> 0
mod.reload() # -> reloaded 2 times
```